# Ionic 2 Modal not displaying correctly

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic2

I am trying to test displaying a modal in Ionic 2 following the [example on the website](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/) however I get the modal displaying as a gray overlay with no content. (as seen in the image).
The project was created using `ionic start demo1 sidemenu --v2`

I just want to display the modal when clicking on the button.

**Calling page...**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyModal } from './modal/modal'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})
export class Page1 {

  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  }
  presentModal() {
    let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(MyModal);
    myModal.present();
  }
```

}

Modal Page...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    template: `
<ion-content>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</ion-content>>
    `
})
export class MyModal {

    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, private params: NavParams) {
    }
}
```

This is rendeing like this in Chrome and MS Edge. But the gray area disapears if the window reduces down to a certain size, but still no content.

Is there something I am missing or is this a known issue?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to solve this.

Issue was that the modal component was not defined in the app module file...

So I have to add MyModal into both the `declarations` and `entryComponents` collections

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';
import { MyModal } from '../pages/page1/modal/modal';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2,
    MyModal
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2,
    MyModal
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: in app.module.ts